# Java iteration problem

Tags: java, iteration, iterable

"Catalog" is a class that stores a collection of "Item" objects. I have chosen to use a List collection for this purpose. So it looks like:

```
public class Catalog {
     List<Item> itemList;
```

The main class must be able to access the Item elements with a for loop that treats a Catalog object like a collection itself. Assume a Catalog object named "catalog:"

```
for (Item items : catalog) {
     //various operations involving item
}
```

Problem: I get the incompatible types error.

```
found: java.lang.Object
requird: Item
```

My Catalog class implements Iterable and has a method iterator() that returns an iterator for the List:

```
public Iterator iterator() {
    Iterator itr = itemList.iterator();
    return itr;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`Catalog` needs to implement `Iterable<Item>` and its `iterator()` method needs to return `Iterator<Item>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Catalog implements Iterable<Item>{
public Iterator<Item> iterator(){
  return itemList.iterator();
}
```

Comment: `:` is not used to specify type inheritance in java.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it implements `Iterable<Item>`, not just `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to implement `Iterable<Item>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a type parameter for the iterator

```
public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    Iterator<Item> itr = itemList.iterator();
    return itr;
}
```

and when `Catalag implements Iterable` make sure it `implements Iterable<Item>`.

Answer (score 0):

It should implement:

```
 Iterable<Item>
```

(note the parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
for(Item item : catalog.itemList) {
    item.getProperty();
    // ... and so on.
}
```

as your `Catalog` class is not iterable, but it's itemList List is.